# Integrity of Hidden Fields: Asp.NET mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field

We have been using asp.net mvc for development. Sometimes, we need to put some hidden fields on form that are shoved in the model by modelbinder (as expected). Nowadays, users can easily temper the form using firebug or other utilities. The purpose of hidden field is mostly to provide some information back to server on as is basis and they are not meant to be changed.

For example in my edit employee form I can put EmployeeID in hidden field but if user changes the employeeID in hidden field, wrong employee will be updated in the database. in this scenario how can we keep the integrity of hidden fields.

Comment: Can always do server-side validation before updating the model. Make sure the logged-in user is authorized to update the specified employee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enforce security to ensure that the person doing the modification has permission to do so.  I'd also put the id in the URL typically rather than a hidden field, relying on the security to ensure that people don't modify things that they shouldn't be able to.  If they do have permission to modify the item when changing the id manually, it shouldn't be a problem.  The important thing is to make sure that a person can't change the id manually and get access to something they shouldn't.  Enforcing server side permissions solves this problem.  You can easily do this using Roles in conjunction with the AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: yes the check is there to make sure that everyone accesses or modifies the record that belongs to him but still i would not want the user to change ID manually and corrupt one of his records in the db.

Answer (score 4):

> if user changes the employeeID in
>   hidden field, wrong employee will be
>   updated in the database

This is a *major* security hole in your website.  In everything you do with web development, no matter how clever someone's code might be or how much you think you'll be ok as long as users don't do something, remember one golden rule: *Never implicitly trust data received from the client.*

In order to modify anything in your website, the user must be logged in.  (Right?)  So in any attempt a user makes to post a form to the website (especially one which can modify data), double-check that the user submitting the form has permission perform the action being requested on the data being specified.

Ideally, every action which isn't completely public and unsecured should have a server-side permissions check.  Never, ever trust what the client sends you.

Answer (score 1):

One potential alternative would be to store that static, single-use information in TempData on the server and not pass it to the client where it could be tampered with. Keep in mind that by default TempData uses Session and has limitations of its own - but it could be an option.